# Where can I find the most recent installer of IIS Express 10?

Tags: installation, iis-express

Our installer installs IIS Express to run a light-weight web server for our client app, and we recently saw a warning popup during installation on some machines saying that "A newer version of IIS Express is already installed".

The one we are including in our installer is the installer one we can find on Microsoft's download site here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264
That version shows up as version 10.0.1741.

On my (developer) machine, when I received the warning, I had version 10.0.1743 installed (I have VS2015 CE and VS2017 CE on that machine).
A colleague had version 10.0.03203 installed (he has VS2015 CE, VS2017 CE and VS2019 CE on his machine).

So: does anyone know where I can find the latest installer of IIS Express (I guess 10.0.03203) so I can include that one in our installer?

UPDATE (20191107) 
As per the suggestion of Lex Li below in the comments, I could indeed just check if IIS Express is installed. Below is the current code we use in our InnoSetup installer, but it still installs and shows a warning about a newer version being present (because it's only checking a specific version most probably). Is there a way to check if the version is anything >= 10 as well?

```
#IFDEF UNICODE
  #DEFINE AW "W"
#ELSE
  #DEFINE AW "A"
#ENDIF

type
  INSTALLSTATE = Longint;

const
  INSTALLSTATE_INVALIDARG = -2;  // An invalid parameter was passed to the function.
  INSTALLSTATE_UNKNOWN = -1;     // The product is neither advertised or installed.
  INSTALLSTATE_ADVERTISED = 1;   // The product is advertised but not installed.
  INSTALLSTATE_ABSENT = 2;       // The product is installed for a different user.
  INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT = 5;      // The product is installed for the current user.

  IIS_EXPRESS_10_x64 = '{63E2B575-D6F7-4572-8EA9-3DAC4208AA2A}'; // IIS 10.0 Express

// Checks the install state of a product (given the product ID)
function MsiQueryProductState(szProduct: String): INSTALLSTATE;
external 'MsiQueryProductState{#AW}@msi.dll stdcall';

// Checks if IIS Express is NOT installed (true if NOT installed)
function IISExpressIsNotInstalled: Boolean;
begin
    Result := not (MsiQueryProductState(IIS_EXPRESS_10_x64) = INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT);
end;
```

Comment: You cannot track the latest IIS Express, as Microsoft keeps updating it for Visual Studio. Improve your installer to detect IIS Express installed, and skip if detected a version. For most web apps, IIS Express version does not matter much.

Answer (score 3):

For me, here's where I found it.

If you navigate to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages there should be one or more folders named similar to Microsoft.VisualStudio.IISExpress.Msi,version=x.x.x.x,chip=x64. Within that folder is a file called _package.json. Open that file to find the URL for the version of IIS installed through visual studio. At the time of this writing, that URL for me is:

https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/b74ade0d-c8a8-4d08-a6e4-2cf72b7e0786/02f244edf2703dfa85dbb2093f824d2e5585426f5f397b2e9c9390a277fafb4f/iisexpress_amd64_en-US.msi